# Nombre de columnas repetidos en los datos

Tags: r

Tengo varios df, quiero abrirlos todos de golpe y unirlos en un solo df

**Los abro**

```
lista1 <- list.files(pattern = "*.*")

lista <- lapply(lista1,
                FUN = function(files) {
                  read_excel(files) })
```

**Los uno**

```
for (i in 1:length(lista)) {
  varname <- paste0("df",i)
  assign(varname, lista[[i]])
}


do.call(rbind, mget(paste0("df", 1:length(lista)))) -> df_unidos
```

Pero he detectado un problema.
Todos los df tienen el mismo número de columnas, con el mismo nombre, pero resulta que hay columnas con el mismo nombre y en cada df están ordenadas de forma diferente.

Por ejemplo, un df puede ser

```
col1 col2  col1
1     A    Z1
2     B    Z2
3     C    Z3
```

y otro df puede ser

```
col1 col1  col2
1     Z1    A
2     Z2    B
3     Z3    C
```

Los dos df tienen 3 columnas, se llaman igual, pero hay dos con el mismo nombre (col1) y colocadas en una posición diferente.

Cuando abro los ficheros con R, a las columnas con el mismo nombre les añade un número para diferenciarlas. Este número depende de la posición que ocupa la columna.

Para el df1

```
col1 col2  col1...3
```

Para el df1

```
col1 col1...2  col2
```

Lo que a la hora de unirlos me provoca un error.

No sé si hay alguna manera de abrir los ficheros obligando que en vez de ponerle un número a las columnas repetidas le ponga un .x o algo por el estilo, o que ordene las columnas antes de cambiarles el nombre.

Comment: Entiendo que el número adicional no es por la posición absoluta de la columna, sino  el orden por el nombre de la columna, es decir `col1, col2, col1` se nombrarían como `Col1, Col2, Col1.1`, en cuyo caso si el orden dentro de las `Col1`  se respeta, no debería haber problema, ahora si las mismas `Col1`  se invierte el orden, no veo la forma de identificar cual es cual.

Comment: read_excel me abre col1,col2,col1 como col1...1 (con 3 puntos) col2, col3...3. Tal vez otra librería me lo abra de forma que me convenga más. –

Comment: Una opción puede ser determinar desde un principio el orden de interés de tus variables `var.ord <- c("col1", "col2", "col3")` y a la hora de cargar los datos, añadir una línea que incluya ese orden `df1 <- df1[,var.ord]` (para cada una de las tablas)

Comment: Ok, leí la documentación y efectivamente el índice que le pone es posicional dentro de todo el vector de nombres. De cualquier forma esto se podría subsanar, el tema es lo que planteaba en mi comentario anterior, imagina que tenemos una columna A y otra B, las dos se llaman Col1, en un data frame aparecen en el orden A y B, y en otro como B y A, si esto ocurre no hay forma de resolverlo, ahora si siempre aparecen con el el mismo orden, aunque sea en cualquier lugar y con columnas intercaladas en el medio, eso si se podría resolver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente `read_xls()` utiliza por defecto el parámetro `.name_repair = "unique"` el cual hace invocar la función `vctrs::vec_as_names()` para rebautizar las columnas,  de esta forma:

```
vctrs::vec_as_names(c('col1', 'col2', 'col1'), repair = "unique")

New names:
* `col1` -> `col1...1`
* `col1` -> `col1...3`
[1] "col1...1" "col2"     "col1...3"
```

El índice agregado es posicional dentro de todos los nombres lo que no nos sirve del todo para unir luego las columnas, la segunda `Col1` puede ser una vez `Col1..3` otra vez `Col1..6`. Sería ideal tener un índice individual por cada nombre de columna, entonces la segunda ocurrencia de `Col1` siempre sería por ejemplo `Col1.2` independientemente de dónde se encuentre. **Importante**: esto es válido únicamente si el orden de las columnas repetidas es siempre el mismo. No resuelve, ni creo que se pueda hacerlo en casos como este:

df1:

```
Col1 Col1
A    1
B    2
```

df2:

```
Col1 Col1
1    A
2    B
```

El resultado en este caso, sería una mezcla de datos entre columnas.

Si no tienes este problema, lo que se me ocurre es 1) no rebautizar los nombres en `read_xls` 2) Crear nuestra propia rutina de renombrado de nombres.

Veamos primero (2):

```
unique_names <- function(x) {
  idx <- ave(x, x, FUN = seq_along)
  ifelse(idx==1, x, paste0(x, ".", idx))
}

unique_names(c('col1', 'col2', 'col1'))
[1] "col1"   "col2"   "col1.2"

unique_names(c('col1', 'col1', 'col2'))
[1] "col1"   "col1.2" "col2"
```

Ahora simplemente leemos las planillas sin renombrar nombres de columnas (`.name_repair = "minimal"`):

```
lista <- lapply(lista1,
                FUN = function(files) {
                  read_excel(files,
                             .name_repair = "minimal") })
```

Y luego aplicamos nuestra nueva rutina:

```
lapply(lista, 
       FUN=function(x) {
         setNames(x, unique_names(colnames(x)))
       }) -> lista
```

Con esto consigues tener al menos nombres consistentes entre las columnas con nombre repetido, lo cual te facilita luego la tarea de unir todos los `data.frames`. Y por cierto, no es necesario el segundo ciclo que haces, simplemente puedes trabajar con la lista: `do.call(rbind, lista)`